# If I do not set LaunchImage, the program's window will initialize incorrectly

Tags: ios

I recently ran into a problem, I downloaded a Demo, but when it is initialized, I found that its screen is always smaller than the mobile phone screen.When I tried a variety of ways, I finally found that because I did not Set LaunchImage

But the problem is, I usually write a small demo when there is no set LaunchImage, why these small Demo display is correct?

Why does LaunchImage cause the interface to display abnormally?

Comment: New apps created in Xcode user a launch NIB/storyboard by default. Your app wil no scale up if there are no launch screens/NIB/storyboard

Comment: Do you mean that the view is smaller (in points) and appears scaled up?

Comment: @rckoenes but when i write some demo by myself. i did not set LaunchImage at all. why those demo run very correct. i mean the windows 
Looks like it should be.

Comment: @johnyu yes , it (the rootView)looks smaller than the phoneScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it perhaps appears scaled up and by "screen is smaller" you mean that in code its size in points is smaller than it should be, then it seems to be an issue that can be traced back to the release of iPhone 5. Before it came out, all iPhones had the same screen size (in points): 320x480. Then came iPhone 5 and its new screen size: 320x568. Apple had to make sure that all previously released apps will work and their layout won't go crazy on a screen a bit larger than the one they were designed to.

The solution was displaying the "old" apps on new iPhone 5 with black bars on top/bottom so their size can stay the same as before. App needed to have its support for iPhone 5 screen explicitly specified in order to display on whole screen and they way you specified that was to add a LaunchImage with the appropriate size for iPhone 5. Lack of that LaunchImage meant that app had to be displayed with black bars. Then same thing happened with iPhone 6 and 6+, which both introduced new screen sizes and still needed to support old apps released before they came out.

Speculation on my side (if someone has some better information on the matter, feel free to edit/comment) is that perhaps you did other demos in newer version of XCode that by default assumes that your app will support all current screen sizes. If the demo project you downloaded was made in an older XCode version then it will not overwrite those settings to not support larger screens if you don't have their specific LaunchImages.

Comment: Thank you very much, completely Solved my question.